# How to get Client Machine's Logged in user info in Node js

Tags: node.js, express, web-applications

I know that we can get the logged in user info to server by using `require("os").userInfo().username` or `process.env.USERNAME`. This returns the  user name info on which the server is hosted and Running.

How can we get the Logged in user info in which the application is running ? .i.e, Client Machine's User info

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: You cannot access this information from JS on the client.

Comment: A Web client (aka, a Web Browser) does not give a Web Server OS access. That would be a pretty big security flaw.